# Internet Explorer box-shadow artefacts on animation

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am making a simple jobs site to test my skills in web development and in IE when i dynamically change the content o the page the bottom box shadow leaves some copies of it...

This is after i dynamically change the content:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this happens. Is it a normal behavior for IE?

Here is some HTML code:

```
    <div id="categories-menu" class="">
    <ul id="categories">
        <li class="category">
            <a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/">All jobs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
            <a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/31">Agriculture</a>
            <a href="" class="pluss">+</a>
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subcategories">
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/32">Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing</a></li>
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/33">Landscape Architect</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
            <a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/34">Education</a>
            <a href="" class="pluss">+</a>
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subcategories">
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/35">College/University</a></li>
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/36">Independent Learning</a></li>
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/37">Libraries</a></li>
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/38">Preschool</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
            <a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/39">Government</a>
            <a href="" class="pluss">+</a>
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subcategories">
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/40">City</a></li>
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/41">County</a></li>
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/42">Federal</a></li>
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/43">University of Wisconsin System</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
            <a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/44">Information Technology</a>
            <a href="" class="pluss">+</a>
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subcategories">
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/45">Computer - Hardware</a></li>
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/46">Computer - Software</a></li>
                <li class="subcategory"><a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/47">Computer Service and Call Center</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
            <a href="/jobs/front/jobs_by_cat/48">Labor</a>
            <ul style="display: none;" id="subcategories">
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

And the css code:

```
    #categories-menu {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 153, 204, 0.1);
    border: 1px dashed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.78);
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: The box-shadow property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4, Chrome, Opera, and Safari 5.1.1. Which version you checking?

Comment: I am testin it on IE10. On firefox it worx perfectly...

Comment: Please provide code and/or jsfiddle to allow use to help you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZP2xt/ it works in IE10.

Comment: I wonder whi it doesn-t work for me. Anyway...this can easly be replaced with a background color. The main problem is the box shadow...could my IE be messed up. I will try to reinstall it. I'll be back ;) with updates

Comment: Loocks like i can't reinstall IE10. It saiz that a more recent version is installed...

Comment: it's unlikely to be the browser being "messed up" and needing reinstall... if it was that badly broken, you'd have much worse problems than this.

Comment: Question: I notice that you're including the old `filter` style to support old IE versions. What happens if you remove this? Normally IE10 should have the filter styles switched off, but it is possible to re-enable them for users of legacy sites. But if you use them an the standard CSS styles at the same time, it can cause some problems. Try removing the `filter` style, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The `filter` style is useless here. I tried to use it because te gradient background of the content did not work in IE. But it does not solve anything

Comment: i fixed the gradient. I just needed to add this line in css: `background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC , #EEEEEE 175px);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i desperately searched the web for a solution. And looks like the box-shadou artefacts are a knoun issue in IE10. It wa easly fixable in IE9 with an `overflow: hidden` on the shaddowed elemen. But in IE10 it can't be fixed anymore.

A workaround would be to remove the shadow before the animation and add it back after the animation is completed.